# read_osm in tmaptools delivers errors

Tags: java, r, openstreetmap

The following line in R:

```
bg = read_osm(bb(c(min(lons)+0.5,min(lats)+0.2,max(lons),max(lats))), type='esri-topo')
```

creates the error message below. What's wrong, and how to fix it?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.cens.spatial.RTileController.getTileValues(RTileController.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:399)
Error in osmtile(x%%nX, y, zoom, type) : could not obtain tile: 65 36 7
```

I have loaded the libs: tmaptools, tmap, rnaturalearth, raster, ncdf4
lons and lats are numeric vectors:
lons
[1]  5.042400  5.127200  5.212000  5.296800  5.381600  5.466400  5.551200  5.636000  5.720800  5.805600  5.890400  5.975200
[13]  6.060000  6.144800  6.229600  6.314400  6.399200  6.484000  6.568800  6.653600  6.738400  6.823200  6.908000  6.992800
[25]  7.077600  7.162400  7.247200  7.332000  7.416800  7.501600  7.586400  7.671200  7.756000  7.840800  7.925600  8.010401
[37]  8.095200  8.180000  8.264800  8.349600  8.434401  8.519200  8.604000  8.688801  8.773600  8.858400  8.943200  9.028000
[49]  9.112801  9.197600  9.282400  9.367201  9.452000  9.536800  9.621600  9.706400  9.791201  9.876000  9.960800 10.045601
[61] 10.130400 10.215200 10.300000 10.384800 10.469601 10.554400 10.639200 10.724001 10.808800 10.893600 10.978400 11.063200
[73] 11.148001 11.232800 11.317600 11.402401 11.487200 11.572001 11.656800 11.741600

lats
[1] 57.02248 57.06742 57.11237 57.15733 57.20227 57.24723 57.29218 57.33712 57.38208 57.42702 57.47197 57.51693 57.56187
[14] 57.60683 57.65178 57.69672 57.74168 57.78662 57.83157 57.87653 57.92147 57.96643 58.01138 58.05632 58.10128 58.14622
[27] 58.19117 58.23613 58.28107 58.32603 58.37098 58.41592 58.46088 58.50583 58.55077 58.59573 58.64067 58.68563 58.73058
[40] 58.77552 58.82048 58.86543 58.91037 58.95533 59.00027 59.04523 59.09018 59.13512 59.18008 59.22503 59.26997 59.31493
[53] 59.35987 59.40483 59.44978 59.49472 59.53968 59.58463 59.62957 59.67453 59.71947 59.76443 59.80938 59.85432 59.89928
[66] 59.94423 59.98917 60.03413 60.07907 60.12403 60.16898 60.21392 60.25888 60.30383 60.34877 60.39373 60.43867 60.48363
[79] 60.52858 60.57352

hoped to get a map area. didnt work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you really need "esri-topo"? If you set e.g. `type = "osm"` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I downloaded all the java stuff from this link:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-windows
Then I had to define the Windows JAVA_PATH according to the recipe here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-java-path-in-windows-and-linux/
Then I had to edit the type-setting in read_osm to type="osm" as kindly suggested by @mgrund in the comment.
Then my programs worked as before.